# How to write to observable by name?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm writing a form filling page using Knockout and based on some old html forms, everything is good but the html forms have a button to copy a set of address data from one set of inputs to another, I'm trying to duplicate similar functionality in my ViewModel using this function:

```
self.CopyData = function (source, target) {
    for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        self[target[i]] = self[source[i]];
    };
};
```

Where source and target are arrays of strings.

However I think that this is going to fail as I'm not writing to the knockout observable instead I'm overwriting it with a value. However I haven't found out how to do this the right way. From the documentation:

> To write a new value to the observable, call the observable and pass
>   the new value as a parameter. For example, calling
>   myViewModel.personName('Mary') will change the name value to 'Mary'.

How do I write to a Knockout observable by name?

Comment: `self[target[i]](self[source[i]]);`

Comment: That looks so wrong to me, will it really work?

Comment: It will if you add the parentheses I forgot: `self[target[i]](self[source[i]]());`

Comment: Please, add a little more information to your question. You're copying one array of string to another array of strings, but, then, where are the observables? where are your viewmodles? Are they observable properties or is it an observable array. Please, so a little more information in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An observable is simply a setter-getter function. You assign a value to an observable by invoking it with the value as an argument. To read the value of an observable, you invoke it with no argument.

To keep things clear, I'll use a couple of variables.

```
self.CopyData = function (source, target) {
    var sourceObs, destObs;
    for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        sourceObs = self[source[i]];
        destObs = self[target[i]];
        destObs(sourceObs());
    };
};
```